# How to limit column width on react-admin List View

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

On a list view with few columns, the columns are very wide. I'd like to limit the width of at least some of these columns (except the last one):

[image]

Still trying to come up to speed on react-admin, react, and material-ui. I'm sure there's some styling involved. Could someone please point me in the right direction? Thanks.

UPDATE:
I added the style as Jozef suggested but no change. Here's what it looks like in Inspect:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two options to customize width of cells.

If you want to set width evenly you can change `table-layout` of Datagrid

```
<Datagrid style={{tableLayout: 'fixed'}} rowClick="edit">
  <TextField source="sourceName" />
  <BooleanField source="active" />
  <TextField source="organizationName" />
</Datagrid>
```

If it is not enough, well, we have to create our custom `Datagrid` with all of its dependencies so we can pass to `TableCell` component specific width. Be it percent or px value. This is not very well [documented](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#the-datagrid-component) so you have to rely on source code which is in `ra-ui-materialui`

Here's the example

```
import {
  Datagrid,
  DatagridBody,
  DatagridCell,
  TextField,
  BooleanField
 } from 'react-admin';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';

const CustomDatagridRow = ({ record, resource, id, onToggleItem, children, selected, basePath }) => (
    <TableRow key={id}>
        <TableCell style={{width="10%"}} padding="none">
            {record.selectable && <Checkbox
                checked={selected}
                onClick={() => onToggleItem(id)}
            />}
        </TableCell>
        {React.Children.map(children, field => (
            <TableCell style={{width: field.props.width}} key={`${id}-${field.props.source}`}>
                {React.cloneElement(field, {
                    record,
                    basePath,
                    resource,
                })}
            </TableCell>
        ))}
    </TableRow>
);

const CustomDatagridBody = props => <DatagridBody {...props} row={<CustomDatagridRow />} />;
const CustomDatagrid = props => <Datagrid {...props} body={<CustomDatagridBody />} />;

<CustomDatagrid style={{tableLayout: 'fixed'}} rowClick="edit">
  <TextField width="20%" source="sourceName" />
  <BooleanField width="20%" source="active" />
  <TextField width="50%" source="organizationName" />
</CustomDatagrid>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried what you suggested with style={{ tableLayout: 'fixed'}}  and it didn't make any difference in the column widths of the table.  Sorry but my experience with react is limited.

Comment: Thats weird. are you sure you put it in `Datagrid` component? If you inspect html `table` tag in chrome dev tools, do you see its style overwritten?

Comment: Yes, I added it just as you said. I'll put a pic in my question showing that it doesn't appear to be overridden???

Comment: It is overwritten and column widths are split evenly. If you add few more columns i think you might notice a difference

Comment: Ah yes, I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`TextField` is a simple `Typography` component.
Since default `Typography` component's `display` css attribute is `inline`, `width` will not work.
You can just change the `display` attribute value to `block` so width will work. :)

```js
  <List>
    <Datagrid rowClick="edit">
      <TextField source="id" sx={{ display: "block", width: 100 }} />
      <TextField source="title" sx={{ display: "block", width: 200 }} />
      <TextField source="content" />
    </Datagrid>
  </List>
```